# Browser extension / send message / how to catch error when content script isn't loaded yet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a browser extension where content and background script exchange messages. When the extension button is clicked, the background script catches it and sends a message to the content script (the content script selects elements in the page and manipulates them):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg, action);
});
```

This all works well when the extension was already active when the page itself was loaded. But when the extension is first loaded, the content script isn't injected yet in any open tab, but the extension button gets displayed and is clickable. If the user clicks on the button, the browser tries to send a message to a non-existing content script, which results in error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

This is normal, but I would like to catch this error, to tell the user to reload the page after the extension was loaded. Wrapping any call in try/catch block doesn't catch anything.

How do I catch this error?

Comment: [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](//stackoverflow.com/a/11598753)

Comment: [Unchecked runtime.lastError when using Chrome API](//stackoverflow.com/a/28432087)

Comment: Indeed 28432087#28432087 is the answer to the question. Thanks!